# Schwinger-Keldysh contour and $i\epsilon$ prescription

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, propagator, wick-rotation, analyticity

In [Tom Hartman](http://www.hartmanhep.net/)'s [notes](http://www.hartmanhep.net/topics2015/4-pathintegrals.pdf) on path integrals, he describes the Schwinger-Keldysh (or "in-in") formalism for calculating vacuum correlators in QFT.

He explains that Lorentzian time-ordered vacuum correlators can be obtained by doing a path integral on a particular spacetime which is part-Euclidean and part-Lorentzian. A diagrammatic representation of this path integral is shown in figure (4.23) at the top of page 44.

He then says something slightly cryptic:

> Actually the usual $i\epsilon$ prescription is just a deformation of the integration contour (that is, integration contour in field space) shown in figure (4.23), and computes exactly the same quantity. So if you’re ever wondered what you were doing with that $i\epsilon$, the answer is the figure in (4.23)!

I don't understand what's going on here. In the past, I've only encountered the $i\epsilon$ prescription in the context of a free field, where the momentum space Feynman propagator is $(k^2-m^2+i\epsilon)^{-1}$. In this case, the $i\epsilon$ can be seen as a deformation of the integration contour in *momentum* space (*not* field space). But Hartman seems to be alluding to something which is true beyond free fields, and which can be understood directly in terms of the path integral over field space.

Could someone explain more concretely what Hartman means here?